# players is not a valid member of DataModel "Game"

Tags: lua, roblox

I searched for this error and couldn't find anything helpful. If you have any questions about my question I would be happy to answer it.

**game.players.player.leaderstas.Money = 100**

Comment: `game.Players` is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Lua is Case-Sensitive, you need to add a capital P to Players like
`game.Players.Player.leaderstats.Money.Value = 100` if leaderstats was what you meant.